# Can't make my Mutation work in vue apollo client

Tags: vue.js, graphql, vue-apollo

I have many hours trying to find the problem, but I can't solve it, my mutation works in my Apollo server play ground, but it doesn't work in my vue application. It's very simple, but only the string values work and not for my float values:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <vs-input class="m-2" placeholder="Nombre" type="text" v-model="producto_nombre"></vs-input>
    <vs-input class="m-2" placeholder="Precio 0.00" type="number" v-model="producto_precio"></vs-input>
    <vs-input class="m-2" placeholder="Peso: 0.00" type="number" v-model="producto_peso"></vs-input>
    <vs-input class="m-2" placeholder="Alto" type="number" v-model="producto_alto"></vs-input>
    <vs-input class="m-2" placeholder="Largo" type="number" v-model="producto_largo"></vs-input>
    <vs-input class="m-2" placeholder="Ancho" type="number" v-model="producto_ancho"></vs-input>
    <vs-input class="m-2" placeholder="Categoría" type="text" v-model="producto_categoria"></vs-input>
    <vs-input class="m-2" placeholder="Subcategoria" type="text" v-model="producto_subcategoria"></vs-input>
    <vs-input class="m-2" placeholder="Proveedor" type="text" v-model="producto_proveedor"></vs-input>
    <vs-input class="m-2" placeholder="Buscar" type="text" v-model="producto_buscar"></vs-input>
    <vs-button @click.native="ingresarProducto()">Ingresar</vs-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      producto_precio: null,
      producto_peso: null,
      producto_alto: null,
      producto_largo: null,
      producto_ancho: null,
      producto_nombre: '',
      producto_categoria: '',
      producto_subcategoria: '',
      producto_proveedor: '',
      producto_buscar:''
    }
  },
  methods:{
    ingresarProducto () {
      console.log(
      this.producto_precio,
      this.producto_peso,
      this.producto_alto,
      this.producto_largo,
      this.producto_ancho,
      this.producto_nombre,
      this.producto_categoria,
      this.producto_subcategoria,
      this.producto_proveedor,
      this.producto_buscar
        )
      this.$apollo
        .mutate({
          // Mutation
          mutation: gql`mutation(
            $name: String!
            $category: String!
            $subcategory: String!
            $weight: Float!
            $high: Float!
            $long: Float!
            $width: Float!
            $provider: String!
            $price: Float!
            $search_like: String!
            ){
              newProduct(
            name: $name
            category: $category
            subcategory: $subcategory
            weight: $weight
            high: $high
            long: $long
            width: $width
            provider: $provider
            price: $price
            search_like: $search_like
              ){
                _id
              }
            }
          `,
          variables: {
            name: this.producto_nombre,
            category: this.producto_categoria,
            subcategory: this.producto_subcategoria,
            weight: this.producto_peso,
            high: this.producto_alto,
            long: this.producto_largo,
            width: this.producto_ancho,
            price: this.producto_precio,
            provider: this.producto_proveedor,
            search_like: this.producto_buscar
          }
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.$vs.notify({
            time: 6000,
            title: '¡Producto creado!',
            text: 'Producto ingresado correctamente.',
            color: 'success'
          })

        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error)
        })
    }
  }

}
```

If I set the values on variables it work good, but not working with my v-model values

Comment: Try using `v-model.number="producto_precio"`, etc. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number